# The target type of this expression must be a functional interface for extended Predicate?

Tags: generics, java-8, predicate

```
abstract class QuadPredicate<T,R, U,V> implements Predicate<T> {

    public abstract boolean test(final T t, final R r, final U u,final V v );

    public boolean test(Object t) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

}
```

Why is below statement giving me *The target type of this expression must be a functional interface*

```
QuadPredicate<String ,String , String ,String > q = (String i, String j, String k,String l) -> {return i.equals(j);};
```

but below version works:

```
QuadPredicate<Object ,Object , String ,String > q = 
                (QuadPredicate<Object, Object, String,String>)new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn").eval(
                "new com.test.QuadPredicate(function(obj, obj2, obj3,obj4) obj.equals(obj2))");

System.out.println(">>>>" + q.test("A", "A", null, null)); //gives true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be an interface, not a class:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface QuadPredicate<T, R, U, V> extends Predicate<T> {

    public abstract boolean test(final T t, final R r, final U u, final V v);

    @Override
    default boolean test(T t) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

}
```

Comment: your solution works for me, but why does it work with my version of QuadPredicate with nashorn?

Comment: @Ajeetkumar I can't really tell, have not used nashorn

Comment: @Ajeetkumar Nashorn is a JavaScript engine and JavaScript is a different programming language having different rules…

Comment: Looks like Java is excusing object returned from Nashorn@